# I am writing a web api code to upload documents in specific folder using csom code using savebinarydirect method, which is failing

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net, sharepoint-library, webapi

I can upload the documents using a console app, but when using the same code in. Net Web API, I am getting an error saying, "Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File" doesn't contain a method "Savebinarydirect".
The DLLs which I'm using in Web API for CSOM are:-

1. Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Portable
2. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.runtime.Portable
3. Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime.Windows

The code is running fine in the console application. Can anyone please help?

CSOM code I was using :

```
using (var filestream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    context.Load(list.RootFolder);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    var fileinfo = new FileInfo(filename);
    var result = Path.GetFileName(filename);
    var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}/", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, caseno);
    //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newfile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl + result);
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl + result, filestream, true);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

This code is working for the console but not for Web API.
I am trying one more CSOM code :

```
string uploadLocation = string.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(caseno))
{
    uploadLocation = string.Format("/{0}/{1}/{2}/", Url,"NewDocLibrary", caseno);
}
else
{
    uploadLocation = string.Format("/{0}/", "NewDocLibrary");
}
FileCreationInformation filecreate = new FileCreationInformation();
byte[] bytefile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
filecreate.Content = bytefile;
filecreate.Overwrite = true;

uploadLocation = uploadLocation + Path.GetFileName(filename);
filecreate.Url = uploadLocation;
list.RootFolder.Files.Add(filecreate);
list.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

It is giving me an error "server relative URLs must start with spweb.serverrelativeurl" in my console.

Comment: which version CSOM dll are you using?

Comment: They all are latest version which have updated 4 days ago.

Comment: still please share exact version of Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File, also can you share screenshot whether it is compile time error or runtime?

Comment: version -16.1.8810.1200 . this is the dll verion I am using for Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Portable.dll. Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File doesn't even contain "SaveBinaryDirect" method under dll Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Portable.dll.

Comment: File class is inside Assembly:  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client (in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll).  Check in this dll

Comment: This dll doesn't work with web api.

Comment: are you sure ? I have not tried...but here is a link https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/create-a-webapi-to-add-edit-delete-the-data-from-a-sharepoint-list/

Comment: why would a dll not work in web api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this issue in detail... SaveDirectBinary method is not available in File Class which is in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable.

Below is screenshot of File class from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Portable.

[image]

You shoul use SaveBinary method only if Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll can't be used in Web API(please share what error you are getting while reference above client Dll.

Why it might be working in CSOM is because you would have been using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll in console app.

Screen shot from Client.dll 
[image]

Update to question to upload file using CSOM
Ref link - https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/upload-file-to-sharepoint-office-365-programmatically-using-c-csom-pnp/

```
                     Web web = ctx.Web;
                     ctx.Load(web);
                     ctx.Load(web.Lists);
                     ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
                     List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("NewDocLibrary");
                     ctx.Load(list);
                     ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
                     Folder folder = list.RootFolder.EnsureFolder("Folder1");
                     ctx.Load(folder);
                     ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();

                     Folder folderToUpload = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folder.ServerRelativeUrl);
                     folderToUpload.UploadFile("LargeFile.txt", "D:\\LargeFile.txt", true);
                     folderToUpload.Update();
                     ctx.Load(folder);
                     ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
                     folderToUpload.EnsureProperty(f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                     var serverRelativeUrl = folderToUpload.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + '/' + "LargeFile.txt";
```

hope this helps...Happy coding..!!!

Comment: I am not sure as if how to use SaveBinary method. Could you please help?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee538595(v%3Doffice.15) - You need to pass FileCreationInformation object to savebinary method.

Comment: updated answer with another way to upload file using csom...